# C redirect stdin to keyboard

Tags: c, stdin, instruments

I have written a smallish C program on Mac OSX that does the following steps:

1. reads some input from stdin and stores input into memory.
2. runs some computations and prints the output to stdio

In between steps 1 and 2, I want to prompt the user and wait for some kind of keyboard input to signal "keep proceeding to step 2". The problem is that stdin has been redirected when the program was called using the command:

```
$ ./simple < input.in
```

I would like to redirect stdin to the keyboard after reading the file and am not sure how to do this. I have tried using

```
fclose(stdin);
freopen("newin", "r", stdin);
```

but stdin fails to read from the keyboard thereafter. Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Some further points:

- The real program is much more involved than this but simple still illustrates my question.
- The reason for this is that I'd like to pause my program during execution so that I have enough time to load the "simple" process into the OSX app called instruments for performance analysis.
- If it helps, some more example code is provided below.

```
int main(void) {

    // STEP 1
    int array[ARRLEN];
    readinput(array, ARRLEN);


    // WAIT FOR KEYBOARD INPUT TO PROCEDE
    // redefine stdin to keyboard
    fclose(stdin);
    freopen("newin", "r", stdin);
    char c[5]; 
    char cmp[5] = ".";
    puts ("Enter text. Include a dot ('.') in a sentence to exit:");

    while (1) {
        fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
        printf("c = %s\n", c);
        // if (strcmp(c, cmp))
        //     break;
        sleep(1);
    }

    // STEP 2
    // do something here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you need to read from file, why you redirecting stdin, when you can just open file with `fopen()` and read from it?

Comment: For the sake of the program, i could do that, but its for a Uni assignment and their method of running/testing the program will be using stdin pipes

Comment: If they run some kind of automatic tests, you better not try reading the keyboard. There will be no one to type on it. If your assignment requires reading from `stdin`, read from `stdin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a file named `newin` that you want to use, your `freopen` invocation will fail. (Besides, you must not close the stream before calling `freopen`, since `freopen` expects a valid stream, which it closes as side effect.) To reopen the standard input to read from the terminal, you need to specify `/dev/tty` as the file name:

```
if (!freopen("/dev/tty", "r", stdin)) {
    perror("/dev/tty");
    exit(1);
}
```

If the program is under your control, there is no reason to reopen `stdin` to begin with - simply open `/dev/tty` as a separate file pointer, and use it to obtain interactive input:

```
FILE *tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");
if (!tty) {
    perror("/dev/tty");
    exit(1);
}
...
while (1) {
    fgets(c, sizeof(c), tty);
...
}
```

In either case, it will not be possible to automate the interactive responses using shell pipes, but that appears to be what you want. Reading from `/dev/tty` is standard practice in command-line programs that support both input redirection and interactive work, such as some Unix editors.

Comment: works like a charm!
Thank you very much, very useful to know as well

Comment: I found that if I go to the proccess' /proc/PID/fd folder, the '0' link is pointing to the file that was redirected in the command line - that's why the keyboard input doesn't work. So, do you know anywhere I can read more about this proccess of redirection (the inner workings of it)? And if I can reverse it to point back to /dev/pts/n instead of opening another file descriptor. Oh, and your answer helped me *a lot*!

Comment: @EnzoFerber I guess you could play around with [`dup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) to make file descriptor 0 point back to the TTY. But I don't understand the details of your situation; you might want to consider asking a separate question detailing the issue and your attempts to resolve it.