# How to read stdin then keyboard input in C?

Tags: c, keyboard, stdin, eof, getchar

I'm trying to read content redirected/piped to my program (e.g. program < test.txt), then display a command prompt and read keyboard input.

The piped input prints correctly, then raises an EOF in stdin. After that, I can't seem to get keyboard input. For example, the following code loops infinitely: the character it prints is -1 (EOF).

What would you suggest to get the keyboard input working?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int ch;

    while (EOF != (ch = getchar())) {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }

    sleep(3);

    while (1) {
        while ('\n' != (ch = getchar())) {
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That would be a very strange way of your program to work. Don't try to make something that is highly unintuitive to others. Programs either take keyboard input or a file input stream (or stdout from another program). If you would want to read a file, use a program argument for that, e.g. `./command -f config`, that would make much more sense to console users.

Comment: Not 100 percent sure that this will work, but maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978444/c-redirect-stdin-to-keyboard.  I think if you are directing from a file to stdin, you may need to do something from within the program to set stdin to be fed from the keyboard.

Comment: You might be able to open `/dev/tty` on some OSes to get console input when stdin is something else.

Comment: @Cheetah There is some processing that I omitted from the code. The reading from stdin and the keyboard are separate parts of the program at separate times. But stdin is still in an EOF state after the processing.

Comment: @Shawn, Jonathon S. Thanks. I did some more research and FILE *tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "r"); worked on Unix.